# Invalid expression term 'bool'

Tags: c#, wpf

I have been working on a application for our help desk team to push out to end users. I would like for these users to be able to add an attachment by using a browse button and eventually by drag and dropping. I have got the email generating, all fields are pulling correctly but the attachment field. I am getting a `Invalid expression term 'bool'` in my attachment code. Any help would be appreciated.

```
//Attachment button
    private void Attach_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {         
        OpenFileDialog dlg = new OpenFileDialog();

        if (bool(dlg.ShowDialog))     
        {
            string FilePath = dlg.FileName.ToString();
            Attachment1.Text = FilePath;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Remove `bool` from your `if` statement.

Comment: I believe this is the intention... `if (dlg.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)`

Comment: It returns `DialogResult`

Comment: ShowDialog *Method*: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.showdialog(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Oh this is WPF, sorry I do not have experience with WPF

Comment: @BlakeThingstad it doesn't. It returns `Nullable<bool>`

Comment: @BlakeThingstad That was the intention but with WPF this expression will not work. if (dlg.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) would have worked if not for WPF.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In WPF the `ShowDialog` method has a return type of `Nullable<bool>`, not of `bool`.

You however misplaced the brackets in your parsing - it should be

```
if ((bool) dlg.ShowDialog())
```

But you should actually be able to use it without a parse like that:

```
if (dlg.ShowDialog() == true)
```

Comment: Can you cast a `DialogResult` to a `bool`??

Comment: @RufusL it has return type `Nullable<bool>` in wpf (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.showdialog(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: `ShowDialog` is a method, not a boolean property.

Comment: Did anyone downvoting this answer actually try it? Because I did, and it does in fact work.

Comment: Sorry, I completely missed that this was wpf. If you edit your answer, the down-voters should be able to remove their votes.

Comment: @Keith Could you please mark this answer accepted if it helped you? And for the people from winform this `if (dlg.ShowDialog() == true)` is perfectly valid in WPF